# Type inference error when typescript generics and class inheritance are used together

Tags: typescript, generics, inheritance, union

```js
class Animal<T extends string> {
  eat(food: T): void {
    console.log('eating ' + food)
  }
}

class Rabbit extends Animal<'carrot'> {}

class Cat extends Animal<'mouse'>{}

type MyPet = Rabbit | Cat
const myPets: Record<string, MyPet> = {
  'aa': new Rabbit(),
  'bb': new Cat()
}

function getPets (name: string): MyPet {
  return myPets[name]
}

const pet = getPets('aa')


// error: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
pet.eat('carrot')
pet.eat('mouse')
```

Please check the source code [[source code replication](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKgUABBAcELQQEoFMCGATA9gOwDYE8IAmSeOci0gI0IEFsAXACx0IDEBXCACgAFVGAMw4BKCAGIAtsnQBLDpIkAnNFjyFxmKgCtkAYwZwA1snwBnUqXHWIARQ7IzDWTktQAkpIAOuZNMYQqBAA5sjYyEqyehAABgCy+CgYOAREADwAKgA0EADSAHwxEADuTFFMEAyoJmaVxZiV+F7IgUrBCmEMsRlFAuixuTEAdG4DRWbNerKChMwtZshdmIIQXkqYzUrOjhDL3UXMqF1mLBy4-QtdDA1JagRDEADqTGFjELK12Jhda5gAbrJ0DIcrJjqdzhBJNUWqhcLhVutNttaipkuoINoOE4ILhZCZKi8IF8lFD4TFbil8JlCiMoKQ2JglBBkAAPVDeXyjGLchgWKCyRgRQSoPQtDKYLAQADepCgzgYvgAXBAnJFsMFZRAgWY9JEvM4cMrVQKNVAoHpMBzFjJlVRMJhfAJSABfUYW7DY65YZUJCnqdLirA5ADk8t8wYgAB8IMHtbrZPqXNhg-kIABeaWasPIZUAIgAEqZc1lNXG9QbsHnBPaqKglMXNRarQwbRBhbgFiWoK66XKJZghtn0xAC8g4ZhcxBgMAIABRJTrJTKvQCL5dVFmMyyYLYQIQVF3Qi-JH4UhegdlhMV4e52tKBkTqcz+eL5er777tCb7e7oIHykIhsEQMKefZYEMTY+Na-QZgwSgOE+EAAPK5KQ3IxKMqYAGqyMgxS7LuADioL5hwVDKkwDAMF4ZiKtOvJ6EwQzaGYQyMsEwDQGAIDAGAfGgBAAD6wkiaJIkQAAmpgHBMgAwhKLSFioQliapgkQDxfF6LgqCbhA9CyKSmTMiyLbYOgtTGuqqYylAaAMNw1YSsqGQiMqfyYICmZmhA7pmA6yBDLgmDBNwwb2SaMYQAA1G29roCILpgK6YDabptSIKgVBUKCJlmRZ+nYIZsJpMGK4Lt8KbSilaV6bJRx5WEBUGUZwaSNJCwplKKUgc0EAJAACosw6ZdluXRvVDCpTg2KSPgQ28sqKAWko6BpFZwQ5INiyphmtkxqgqDBsq4T4aNOUOSIXYxtlx1EnhECTdwiUpcI2AGEmISLAttTcNg7I5iqcEmm5-XzcN+0qAwMm7nNP0ANr-dIAC6yVaTNPzDRmoQMD9YWHcGiV8WAzQMEM9lheV6wMITJOLOTRxhe1WLILTYAANx-Q9T0iCIDMOW1HWs0TYACWpqkQBkjhdPVCy1OLYkabxhleIyVxNC0Ur6biJg5LOLKTF0zptusijBrwvXIHAjGwr46qOMAHDOB2wbE2LCviZwWwvEyADKLY0SpHvqZpoCkKmvtMHWLT4NJTL+bgTtJrRECUdRtH0TqTEsWxbSccAAhmMUEThxAOEPQnSczRRVE0XRwAMdnrHsfnlcVnyECpnEjItLJUdwmEoQp2ndeZ4xzHN203G8WAQA)], The generic method is called by using the joint type of two subclasses. The parameter type is inferred as `never`. Shouldn't it be `carrot | mouse`。

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your code doesn't allow TS to work properly by being not precise enough with some of the type definitions. This code works as expected:

```
class Animal<T extends string> {
  eat(food: T): void {
    console.log('eating ' + food)
  }
}

class Rabbit extends Animal<'carrot'> {}

class Cat extends Animal<'mouse'>{}

type MyPet = Rabbit | Cat
const myPets = {
  'aa': new Rabbit(),
  'bb': new Cat()
}

function getPets <T extends keyof typeof myPets>(name: T): typeof myPets[T] {
  return myPets[name]
}

const pet = getPets('aa')

pet.eat('carrot')
pet.eat('mouse') // error: Argument of type '"mouse"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"carrot"'
```

See [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKgUABBAcELQQEoFMCGATA9gOwDYE8IAmSeOci0gI0IEFsAXACx0IDEBXCACgAFVGAMw4BKCAGIAtsnQBLDpIkAnNFjyFxmKgCtkAYwZwA1snwBnUqXHWIARQ7IzDWTktQAkpIAOuZNMYQqBAA5sjYyEqyehAABgCy+CgYOAREADwAKgA0EADSAHwxEADuTFFMEAyoJmaVxZiV+F7IgUrBCmEMsRlFAuixuTEAdG4DRWbNerKChMwtZshdmIIQXkqYzUrOjhDL3UXMqF1mLBy4-QtdDA1JagRDEADqTGFjELK12Jhda5gAbrJ0DIcrJjqdzhBJNUWqhcLhVutNttaipkuoINoOE4ILhZCZKi8IF8lFD4TFbil8JlCiMoKQ2JglBBkAAPVDeXyjGLchgWKCyRgRQSoPQtDKYLAQADepCgzgYvgAXBAnJFsMFZRAgWY9JEvM4cMrVQKNVAoHpMBzFjJlVRMJhfAJSABfUYW7DY65YZUJCnqdLirA5ADk8t8wYgAB8IMHtbrZPqXNhg-kIABeaWasPIZUAIgAEqZc1lNXG9QbsHnBPaqKglMXNRarQwbRBhbgFiWoK66XKJZghtn0xAC8g4ZhcxBgMAIABRJTrJTKvQCL5dVFmMyyYLYQIQVF3Qi-JH4UhegdlhMV4e52tKBkTqcz+eL5er777tCb7e7oIHykIhsEQMKefZYEMTY+Na-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-0nWdIgiKzDltR1XPk2AAlqapwOOF09ULLUMtiRpvGGV4jJXE0LRSvpuImDks4spMXTOm26yKMGvCfXAjGwr46qOMAHDOB2wYU9LKviZwWwvEyADKLY0Sp3vqZpoCkKmAdMHWLTvTJKoOq7Sa0RAlHUbR9E6kxLFsW0nHAAIZjFBEUcQDhJ3+bgKczRRVE0XRwAMbnrHsYX1e1x65dxIyLSybHcJhKEacZ432eMcxbdtNxvFgEAA)

In your original code you were using

```
const myPets: Record<string, MyPet> = {
  'aa': new Rabbit(),
  'bb': new Cat()
}
```

So TS will lose the information that `myPets.aa` is a `Rabbit`. It will trat `myPets.aa` as type `MyPet`. And since the types `'mouse'` and `'carrot'` have nothing in common, you cannot feed that `pet`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it still doesn't solve my problem. Because in my program, pet will be a joint type. Referring to your answer, if name is a variable, it still won't work. 
This is my code:

Comment: The text is too long. I put it in the next answer